# is there a wordpress "lightbox" type of plugin that works on the iPhone?

Tags: wordpress

Here I go again,

Anyone know if there's a Wordpress "lightbox" style  plugin that works with mobile devices , specifically the iPhone  -- or if theres a way to tweek one to be used ?

I've tried Slimbox2 Shadowbox JS and a few others -- but they all seem to break on the iphone  -- specifically when the browser is re-sized.

It's a bummer because I rreally like the way my site looks on the iphone - except for showing images .

thanks -MW

Comment: I'd still like to know if there is a plugin that would accomplish this ... though .. 

- for those interested I'm using a workaround by using Browser Specific CSS and creating a different class specifically for the iphone that will show but not link the image .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes nearly :-) There is great AND USABLE expample at http://www.jaipho.com/ but it is not in plugin form

Comment: I got around to checking JAIPHO out - very cool - thanks . I ended up doing little tweaking of the javascript for more automated loading and it's a great sollution - thanks -